Source of Goethe quote "Outwardly limited, Boundless to inward"
Found this quote in "Piano Playing: With Piano Questions Answered" by Josef Hofmann, published in 1976:

Goethe's great word expresses most tersely what I mean:

Outwardly limited,
Boundless to inward.


I feel like something got lost in translating this quote to English, so I wonder what's the source and whether there's a more faithful translation of said quote?

This is from Goethe’s Morphologie:

Die zweite Gunst der von oben wirkenden Wesen ist das Erlebte, das Gewahrwerden, das Eingreifen der lebendig-beweglichen Monas in die Umgebungen der Außenwelt, wodurch sie sich erst selbst als innerlich Grenzenloses, als äußerlich Begrenztes gewahr wird. Über dieses Erlebte können wir, obgleich Anlage, Aufmerksamkeit und Glück dazu gehört, in uns selbst klar werden; andern bleibt aber auch dies immer ein Geheimnis.
Johann Wolfgang von Goethe (1822). Zur Morphologie, Ersten Bandes Viertes Heft. In Schriften Zur Morphologie: Morphologische Hefte, page 275. Stuttgart: J. G. Cottasche.

Here are a couple of English translations with different flavours:

The second gift from the Beings who work above us is experience, awareness, the apprehension by the living, moving Monad of its surroundings, through which first it becomes conscious of itself as something inwardly limitless and outwardly limited. And this experience can become luminous to ourselves, though for this we require opportunity, attentiveness, and luck, but for other men it too remains a mystery.
Translated by F. Melian Stawell and Nora Purtscher-Wydenbruck (1883). The Wisdom of Goethe, page 67. New York: Carlton House.


The second favour bestowed by forces working on us from on high is the monad’s inner experience, gradual apprehension of, then intervention in, the environments of the external world, the monad here being seen as a lively-mobile entity which, only by this process of intervention, actually becomes conscious of its own being as something unlimited within, but limited without. It is by this experience, though aptitude, attentiveness and luck also count, that we can reach clarity within ourselves; for some, however, this too must always remain a mystery.
Translated by Elisabeth Stopp (1998). Maxims and Reflections, page 47. Penguin.

